# React hooks updating a parent state from multiple child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

My parent component makes copies of child component onClick. My goal is for every child component, after a user inputs a select value and a textfield value it appends onto the parent component's map value. I used an approach that passes in a function that edits the map object, but after console logging I realize it just resets the map value for every child component submission. Any suggestions on how to fix this problem?

ex) if user picks instagram with 'www.instagram.com/user' in one child component and facebook with 'www.facebook.com/user' in the other child component, the parent component will ultimately have a map of both key value pairs.

Parent component (Admin.js)

```js
const Admin = () => {
  const links = new Map();
  const [newLink, setNewLink] = useState([]);

  const addLinkToMap = (type, url) => {
    links.set(type, url);
  }

  return (
    <>
      {newLink ? newLink.map(child => child) : null}
        <Button onClick={() => {
           setNewLink(
             [ ...newLink, 
               <AddNewLink key={Math.random()} linkMap={addLinkToMap}/>
             ]
        )}}>
          Add new social media
        </Button>
    </>
  );
}

export default Admin;
```

Child component (AddNewLink.js)

```js
const AddNewLink = props => {
  const [socialMedia, setSocialMedia] = useState('');
  const [url, setUrl] = useState('');
  const linkMap = props.linkMap;

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    linkMap(socialMedia, url);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <FormControl>
        <InputLabel>Select Social Media</InputLabel>
          <Select
            value={socialMedia}
            onChange={e => {setSocialMedia(e.target.value)}}
          >
            <MenuItem value={'facebook'}>Facebook</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={'instagram'}>Instagram</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem value={'tiktok'}>TikTok</MenuItem>
          </Select>
      </FormControl>
      <form>
        <TextField label="Enter link" onChange={e => {setUrl(e.target.value)}}/>
      </form>
      <div>
        <Button onClick={() => handleSubmit()}>Submit</Button>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default AddNewLink;
```

Comment: You need to have a separate state or an object with 3 keys for each child component.
And send that object down as the prop to the child component.
{ 'fb' : 'something', 'insta': 'something', 'tiktok': 'something' }.
And make a callback function and send it down as prop, which runs in parent. It will check first which component is calling the function and update that state accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that whenever you set the state with a call to `setLink` your function gets called again, which means the value of the variable `links` resets every time the state is changed, one way to overcome this issue is to use a `useState` call insted of creating a variable for the `links` map. like so:

```
const [links, setLinks] = useState({});

const addLinkToMap = (type, url) => {
    setLinks({
       ...links,
       type: url
     });
}
```